# preg_match "Compilation failed: missing )"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

its probably a stupid fault but I have a regex what should match on

- allalaa
- afkdsf[]
- afadf43fds["guyish"]

but not on strings starting with a number

here is the code

```
preg_match('~^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(\[(?P<array>"(?:.*(?:(?<!\\)(?>\\\\)*\").*|.*)+(?:(?<!\\)(?>\\\\)*"))\]|\[\]|)$~',trim($item[0],"    \r"),$matches)
```

but when I execute it I get the error `Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 95`

while when I execute it [here](http://l2y.eu/dddd4) it works fine?

whats wrong with the code?

**UPDATE**

readable regex:

```
~
   ^
   [A-Za-z]
   [A-Za-z0-9]*
   (
      \[
      (?P<array>
      "
      (?:
          .*
          (?:
             (?<!\\)
             (?>\\\\)*
             \"
           )
           .*
        |
           .*
        )+
        (?:
           (?<!\\)
           (?>\\\\)*
           "
         )
       )
       \]
     |
     \[\]
     |
   )$
~x
```

Comment: Regex: now you have two problems. The reason you can't tell what's wrong with this code is that *it has become unreadable*. Do something to improve readability and you will find the solution too.

Comment: @j0k something like `gdsg["hello"]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This regex is insane. I have a hard time believing you really need such a complicated one.

In any case the problem is that PHP is consuming the backslash for the PHP string. So you have to escape all the backslashes with another backslash.

And considering the number of backslashes you already have you'll probably go a little nuts doing it.

See also: [Leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)

Comment: That Wikipedia link is awesome. Never knew that had a name. Such a nice one even :)

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses You'll end up with "write only code". Another wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_language

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the regex looks ugly. To get it to compile, though, you just need to change both instances of

```
(?<!\\)(?>\\\\)*
```

to

```
(?<!\\\\)(?>\\\\\\\\)*
```

and both

But I wouldn't trust this regex to work reliably. Too many `.*`s for my taste.